# TThread Not Releasing Handle

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have the following service written with Delphi 2007 which I find is not releasing the thread Handle.  The functions **CurrentMemoryUsage** and **GetOpenHandles** are functions to return memory used and the number of handle used by the application.  The Timer fires each second, creating a thread which is immediately destroyed.  And I can see in my log the **Number of Open Handles** increments by one each time.  This is a very basic threading question.

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
private
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;


procedure TMyService.MyTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
    MyThread : TMyThread;
begin
    MyThread := TMyThread.Create(True);
    MyThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
    MyThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    MyThread.Resume;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
   appendtolog((FormatFloat('Memory used: ,.# K', CurrentMemoryUsage / 1024))+',Number of Handles:'+inttostr(GetOpenHandles)) ;
end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure TMyService.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  appendtolog('thread terminiated');
end;
```

Comment: Delphi version?  Get used to adding your delphi version, please don't make people guess.

Comment: Sorry - Version is D2007

Comment: @warren In fact this code will leak on every extant version of Delphi!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have forgotten to call the inherited `Destroy`. That is what frees the system resources associated with the thread.

```
destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  appendtolog((FormatFloat('Memory used: ,.# K', 
    CurrentMemoryUsage / 1024))+',Number of Handles:'+inttostr(GetOpenHandles));
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: +1, better might be to swap those two lines if OP wants to log state after thread destroy ;)

Comment: @TLama Yes maybe so. I am just in the habit of putting the `inherited` last. But since this is logging I take your point.

Comment: Yes - that was it!!!!!  And this isn't the first time I had ever done this.  But all other times were on VCL objects which would actually drain memory, and were easier to spot with Task Manager.  Thank you.